# CSS ordering with PHP include

Tags: php, css

I am staring to incorporate PHP in order to streamline my site.

First of all I am using php include to call a header which is used accross all pages.

the header links to a specific stylesheet stylesheet_header, and then the rest of the page uses another stylesheet, stylesheet_content.

The page has this basic layout:

```
wrap div
php include header
content div
content div
footer div
```

problem: once the header is called, it's stylesheet (stylesheet_header) is applied to the rest of the page.

I thought the solution would be to call the content_stylesheet after the header, this partly works but alters some position formatting in both the header and the content.

Is there an an obvious solution?

Comment: Yes, write your classes so that they don't conflict with eachother throughout the page, and prefix your CSS with relevant containers for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stylesheets are not scoped based on where they are included in the page, only based on the rules within them. So the following stylesheet rule always applies to all `p` elements on the page, wherever the rule itself appears:

```css
p { font-size: 50%; }
```

The obvious solution to this is to give each container within your page an ID or class which can be used to scope the rules more tightly. Remember that an ID must always be unique across the rendered page, so any block which might be included more than once on the page should be identified by a class instead (this includes things like the content of a search form, even if your current design has it in a unique placement).

So you might have separate rules like so:

```css
#header p { font-size: 50%; }
#main_content p { font-size: 100%; }
.sidebar_block p { font-size: 90%; }
```

In general, you'll want to group your style rules by which blocks they apply to, so you will find yourself with lots of rules next to each other with the same prefix. You can save on the redundancy of this by using a server-side CSS pre-processor such as LESS or SCSS (SASS) which supports nested rules.

LESS was originally developed in JavaScript, and SASS/SCSS in Ruby, but implementations of both are available in PHP, e.g. [these from leafo.net](http://leafo.net/). Both would allow you to write this, which would be rendered as the same CSS as the above example:

```css
#header {
    p { font-size: 50%; }
    // other rules within #header
}
#main_content {
    p { font-size: 100%; }
    // other rules within #main_content
}
.sidebar_block {
    p { font-size: 90%; }
    // other rules within .sidebar_block
}
```

Finally, if you are using an HTML5 doctype (and have taken appropriate precautions for older browsers) you can use "semantic" containers instead of `div` elements with IDs or classes, so that (along with a CSS pre-processor) you could end up with this (where `<header>`, `<main>`, and `<aside>` are all [new elements in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list)):

```css
header {
    p { font-size: 50%; }
    // other rules within #header
}
main {
    p { font-size: 100%; }
    // other rules within #main_content
}
aside {
    p { font-size: 90%; }
    // other rules within .sidebar_block
}
```